# My Vue3 Class Component Typescript application gets slower to compile/build when I import bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, sass, vue-cli, vue-class-components

I realized that my application was much slower to build with vue-cli (either a build production or a simple dev server).

I import bootstrap this way in a SCSS file that re-writes some rules that is imported in all my other SCSS components.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Here are the build time comparison screens :

[Build with bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcfXb.png)

[Build without bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYxTg.png)

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Depending on what you call "re-writes some rules", couldn't you import the minified css instead of the scss files?

Comment: Are you including this SCSS in `additionalData`/`prependData` in your `sass-loader` config?

Comment: Because all my project is in SCSS, I reviewed the size of the breakpoint, the theme color, the inputs etc.. So the minified version would not fit my needs..

Comment: I just realized that my `webpack.config.js` was not taken into account, I am going to investigate it to include `additionalData/prependData` in my `sass-loader`, I will keep you informed to give you a feedback

Comment: However I do not understand what the `additionalData` is used for and what it will change in my case, I understood that it was to inject variables?

However my problem is related to bootstrap build time

Comment: Just want to suggest that Vue-CLI is going to be deprecated soon, and it's officially recommended to create Vue project with Vitejs for Vue 3.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the imports from my components and adding my scss file in the 'loaderOptions' like as below

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/base.scss";`
      },
    }
  }
};
```